# What does this error message mean (creating an input-file for MODifieR) and how to fix it?

Tags: r

I am trying to create an input-file that can be used for different types of module-identification packages in the "MODifieR"-program, but I get this error message: "The condition has a length>1".

[image]

I am still pretty new to R and have just started using these programs so I have no idea what the message means or how to fix it... Greatful for any help!

I haven't tried anything yet, apart from restarting R and reloading all packages/code, as I have little idea of what I am doing :)

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. Instead please provide a minimally reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.